# HTML and CSS background image refuses to work

Tags: html, css

I've been developing a basic site to test my skills, and I wanted to have an image be the background. I believe all my code is correct, the rest of the CSS loads (font, text colour and background colour), except for the image. What am I doing wrong?

```css
body {
    background-color: darkviolet;
    background-image: url ("starrysky.jpg") ;
    
}
h1 {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
p {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Test site </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Test heading</h1>
        <p> Hellooooo </p>

    </body>
    <style>
        div {
            background-image: url('starrysky.jpg');
        }
    </style>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you got your path the the image correct? Use the Newtork Tab of the developer tools in your browser (generally f12) to check for missing resources.\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just noticed there is a space between  url("starrysky.jpg")  in your css file
delete the space and delete the style tag in you html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Test site </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1>Test heading</h1>
    <p> Hellooooo </p>

</div>
</body>
</html>


body {
    background-color: darkviolet;
    background-image: url("starrysky.jpg") ;
    
}
h1 {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
p {
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, maybe it's because I did "starrysky.jpg" and not 'starrysky.jpg'?

Comment: @Chel No, it probably means your image file is not in the same directory as your HTML file, or it doesn't have the exact name you have used.

Comment: This and MrVang's answer are both correct. You have a syntax error and a lack of a div element both.

Comment: It's not a syntax error, I even copied the filename of the image to be sure. I added a div and the image is still not showing up.

Comment: you wrote url ("starrysky.jpg") but you need url("starrysky.jpg")  see the space between url and ("starrysky.jpg")... it causes a syntax error. css syntax errors do not send an error code. If there is an issue in css code the code is simply ignored. which is why troubleshooting css is notoriously difficult.  just delete that space and you good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Which div are you selecting, there isn't a div in your HTML code.

You should try this:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Test heading</h1>
        <p> Hellooooo </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This and MBoisvenue's answer are both correct. You have a lack of a div element and a syntax error both.

Comment: It's true that the commentor can just add a div but the background image will only appear behind whatever the div holds AND it is not good practice to use embedded css styles.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to use **internal CSS**, it must be between `<head></head>`

**and**
if `starrysky.jpg` is same directory with style.css
you have to use like blow in internal CSS.
`url('./style/starrysky.jpg')`

---

```
<head>
  .....
 <style>
  div{
    background-image: url('./style/starrysky.jpg');
  }
 </style>
</head>
```

Comment: Both of your assertions are false. Test them out. (It _is_ good practice for certain elements to occur in certain places, but rarely required by browsers.)